Precision bombing problem in probability
This problem was asked in my university exam.

The problem says that in a precision bombing there is $50\%$ chance that any one bomb will strike the target.
$2$ direct hits are required to destroy the target completely.
How many bombs must be dropped to give a $99\%$ chance to destroy the target? 
The solution involved $$1 - \left(p \ \{X = 0\} + p \ \{X = 1\}\right) \geq 0.99,$$
where $X$ is the number of success and $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, 0.5).$

But, this gives $p \ \{X \geq 2\}$. Why will we drop bombs after hitting the target twice? 
This is also the solution I found on most sites on internet. Is it really correct? What am I missing?

Shouldn't it be solved using negative binomial?
Edit

As mentioned by David K in the answer below by negative binomial approach 
for $2$ success I get the following distribution for some $n$ bombs 
$$\dbinom{n - 1}1p^2(1 - p)^{n-2}\leq 0.01$$
now CDF of this must be $\geq 0.99$
$$\sum_{i = 2}^{n}\dbinom{i - 1}1p^2(1 - p)^{i-2}\geq 0.99$$
which occur first at $n = 11$ so if n >= 11 we will have a 0.99 probability that the second hit lies within n meaning we destroyed the target.
and when we use
$$1 - \left(p \ \{X = 0\} + p \ \{X = 1\}\right) \geq 0.99,$$
$$1 - \dbinom{n}0p^{0}(1 - p)^{n} - \dbinom{n}1p^{1}(1 - p)^{n-1} \geq 0.99,$$
$$1 - \dbinom{n}00.5^{n} - \dbinom{n}10.5^{n} \geq 0.99,$$
and solving this we get n >= 11
which is in accordance with negative binomial result.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

I don't understand your question.  The problem asks for a number of bombs that gives you at least a $.99$ chance of getting two hits.  Of course, in practice, you'll stop after you have your two hits (if you drop sequentially, which isn't stated).  So what?

"Why will we drop bombs after hitting the target twice" - there is no sense of sequence here, consider the bombs dropped all at once.

Two ways we can interpret the phrase "how many bombs must be dropped" are: (1) we start dropping bombs one at a time, and stop when the goal is accomplished; (2) we decide in advance how many bombs must be dropped, drop them all, and then see if the goal was accomplished. In the first interpretation, there is no $99%$ chance; at any point in time the goal either is accomplished or not. In the second interpretation it makes sense to talk about a $99%$ chance.

In the "negative binomial" approach, what you have is that the probability that you will destroy the target with the $10$th bomb and not with any previous bomb, $P(n=10)$, is slightly less than $0.01$. That does not in any way imply that you have a $0.99$ cumulative probability to destroy the target with one of the first $10$ bombs. In fact, the cumulative probability, $P(n \leq 10)$, is only $0.98926$. (This is not fun to compute. I used https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/nb1.html.) You need $11$ bombs for $99%$ probability, in agreement with the binomial approach.

In short, you used the negative binomial distribution incorrectly and therefore got the wrong answer.

Let's put it this way. You say that if $\dbinom{n - 1}1(0.5)^{n} \leq t$ then we have a $1 - t$ probability to destroy the target with $n$ bombs. OK, let $n=2$ and $t=0.25$. Indeed, $\dbinom{2 - 1}1(0.5)^{2} = 0.25$, so we have a $1 - t = 0.75$ chance to destroy the target with $2$ bombs according to your method. That's a bad method.

As pointed out in comments, it makes sense to imagine that we drop all the bombs and then assess afterward whether the target was destroyed.
This is consistent with how you might imagine a bombing raid having been planned in the second world war: you would send out a lot of bombers in formation, each with a plan to drop its bombs on a particular target. Actually assessing the number of hits so that you could call off or redirect bombers during the raid was not practical.
There is, however, an alternative interpretation in which drop one bomb at a time and check results after every bomb, but we have a finite stock of $n$ bombs and we want to know if there's a $99\%$ chance we will destroy the target before we run out of bombs. In this case you can imagine that the number of hits is either $0$, $1$, or $2$ because we stop bombing after the second hit.
In that interpretation, we still end up with a probability distribution that depends on $n$.
The probability that we get no hits -- that is, every one of the $n$ bombs misses -- is
$\left(\frac12\right)^n = \binom n0 \left(\frac12\right)^n$
and the probability that we get exactly one hit is
$n \left(\frac12\right)^n = \binom n1 \left(\frac12\right) \left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}$.
These are the same probabilities as for the events $Y = 0$ and $Y = 1$
if $Y$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $\frac12$.
What's different from the binomial distribution is just that the entire remaining probability is all on the outcome $2$, never distributed over higher-valued outcomes.
That is, the probability distribution we get if we stop after the second hit
looks just like what we would get if we took the binomial distribution
$\operatorname{Bin}\left(n, \frac12\right)$
but reassigned the probabilities of all outcomes greater than $2$
to the outcome $2$.
Another way to look at it is that we end up with a variable $X$ that has the same distribution as
$\min\{Y,2\}$ where $Y \sim \operatorname{Bin}\left(n, \frac12\right)$.
That is, in every case where we scored two hits before we ran out of bombs,
where continuing to bomb could have produced a value greater than $2$ from the binomial distribution, we stopped bombing and therefore the result is capped at $2$.
Now it should be easy to see that
$$ \mathbb P(X = 2) = \mathbb P(\min\{Y,2\} = 2) = \mathbb P(Y \geq 2). $$
Consider the example $n = 4$. With probability
$\mathbb P(X=0) = \frac{1}{16}$, we drop all four bombs and miss every time. With probability $\mathbb P(X=1) = \frac14$, we drop all four bombs and score only one hit. With probability $\frac14$, we score two hits with the first two bombs and stop there; with probability $\frac14$, we score one hit with the first two bombs, get our second hit with the third bomb, and then stop, and with probability $\frac{3}{16}$, we score one hit with the first three bombs and another hit with the fourth bomb.
(I leave it to you to check all of these probabilities.)
Confirming that this covers all cases,
$$ \frac{1}{16} + \frac14 + \frac14 + \frac14 + \frac{3}{16} = 1, $$
and in the last three cases we have exactly two hits, so
$$\mathbb P(X=2) = \frac14 + \frac14 + \frac{3}{16} = \frac{11}{16}.$$
But for $n=4$ we have $Y \sim \operatorname{Bin}\left(4, \frac12\right)$,
so $\mathbb P(Y = 0) = \mathbb P(Y = 4) = \frac{1}{16}$,
$\mathbb P(Y = 1) = \mathbb P(Y = 3) = \frac14$,
and $\mathbb P(Y = 2) = \frac38$. Hence
$$ \mathbb P(Y \geq 2)
= \mathbb P(Y = 2) + \mathbb P(Y = 3) + \mathbb P(Y = 4) = \frac{11}{16}, $$
and in summary,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y = 0) &= \mathbb P(X = 0), \\
\mathbb P(Y = 1) &= \mathbb P(X = 1), \\
\mathbb P(Y \geq 2) &=  \mathbb P(X = 2).
\end{align}
You will get the same last three equations for any value of $n$; the only thing that changes is exactly what is the probability on each equal side.
So it's sufficient to compute $\mathbb P(Y \geq 2)$, and then we have the probability of destroying the target, which is the same whether we stop bombing after the second hit or keep on dropping bombs.

So why not use negative binomial?
A negative binomial distribution answers the question of which bomb finally destroys the target, assuming that we have an infinite supply of bombs to drop and drop them one at a time.
In that case we could take the distribution of the second hit where the individual probability of each hit is $\frac12$, and look for the outcome that is exceeded less than $1\%$ of the time.
That is, we have outcomes $2$ through $k$ which together have at least $99\%$ probability, and outcomes $k+1$ through $\infty$ which together have less than $1\%$ probability.
We want the minimum such $k$. This is a well-defined restatement of the problem and in principle you could solve it this way. It might be instructive to try doing this and compare the procedure with what you have to do to solve the problem the usual way,
keeping in mind that the usual formulas for negative binomial probabilities give you only the probability that the $k$th bomb is the second bomb to hit the target. To find the number of bombs you must have in your arsenal in order to have $99\%$ probability to destroy the target, you need to add up the probabilities that the $2$nd bomb destroys the target, the $3$rd bomb, the $4$th bomb, and so on up to bomb number $n$.

I understood the way we are using negative binomial but how does X = min{Y,2} makes P(X = 2) = P(Y>= 2)? doesn't it still mean we are accounting probability of all outcomes where we bomb the target more than twice?

It's because $\min{Y,2} = 2$ if and only if $Y \geq 2$. I have spelled this out with a much more explicit example now. Remember, $Y$ is not the number of hits. But I've also edited the answer to say that $X$ has the same distribution as $\min{Y,2}$ rather than that these are the same variable, to emphasize that we do not actually need to drop all the bombs in every case.
